# Cannot import js file or display image with Thymeleaf

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

So I'm building a Spring Boot project with Thymeleaf, with the file structure like this:

```
src
 |_main
      |_ java
      |_ resources
               |_ static
                      |_ images
                             |_ image.jpg 
                      |_ js
                          |_ imagetodata.js
               |_ templates
                      |_ image_history.html
```

In the HTML file, I wrote `<script th:src="@{js/imagetodata.js}"></script>` and `<img id="imageInput" th:src="@{images/image.jpg}" alt="Image">` but the console said "404 Not Found" or "net:: ERR_ABORTED 404".

What should I do to fix this? I've tried many ways and URL but the problem is still here, and also I didn't use Spring Security or something. Here's my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.13'
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.11.0'
    implementation 'commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:1.4'
    runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
    providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding / before js and images.

Like :-

```
<script th:src="@{/js/imagetodata.js}"></script> 
<img id="imageInput" th:src="@{/images/image.jpg}" alt="Image">
```

and you can add antmatchers code if you haven't added in your security config file

Like :-

```
.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(
                "/**",
                "/js/**",
                "/css/**",
                "/img/**",
                "/scss/**",
                "/fonts/**",
                "/icon/**").permitAll()
```

from the above code add the required one's

Comment: so I have to import spring security and config the file? Also adding "/" didn't work.

Comment: firstly add antmatchers in config file then check